# Getting sub-array from a 2D double[][] array

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a sub-array from `double[][]` 3x3 matrices (to calculate a determinant). I keep getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Any idea why ?

```
public double[][] get2DSubArray(double[][] largeArray, int rowStartIndex, int rowEndIndex, int columnStartIndex, int columnEndIndex) {
    double[][] subArray = new double[rowEndIndex-rowStartIndex+1][columnEndIndex-columnStartIndex+1];
    for (int row = rowStartIndex; row < rowEndIndex; row++) {
        subArray[row] = Arrays.copyOfRange(largeArray[row], columnStartIndex, columnEndIndex);
    }
    return subArray;
}
```

Comment: Do you know which index values result in exception?

Comment: The exception happens when I input a 3x3 matrix, with indices (1,2,1,2) (e.g. rowStartIndex = 1, rowEndIndex = 2, etc...)

Comment: I have updated the answer with the above inputs.

Comment: I don't get any exception for those inputs: http://ideone.com/P9qn4N. Please include a stack trace and a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it has something to do with array initialization, the `array` passed to the method does not seem to be 3x3. E.g, following does not produce an Exception:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double[][] array = new double[][]{{1d,1d,1d},{2d,2d,2d},{3d,3d,3d}};
    double[][] subArray = get2DSubArray(array, 1, 2, 1, 2);
    for(double[] arrayElement : subArray){
        for(double number : arrayElement){
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
}

public static double[][] get2DSubArray(double[][] largeArray, int rowStartIndex, int rowEndIndex, int columnStartIndex,
        int columnEndIndex) {
    double[][] subArray = new double[rowEndIndex - rowStartIndex + 1][columnEndIndex - columnStartIndex + 1];
    for (int row = rowStartIndex; row < rowEndIndex; row++) {
        subArray[row] = Arrays.copyOfRange(largeArray[row], columnStartIndex, columnEndIndex);
    }
    return subArray;
}
```

**Update**

Although the above solution does not produce an Exception, it does not produce correct output as well. Mainly because of the following reasons:

- Third argument for `Arrays.copyOfRange` method is exclusive, so we have to pass `columnEndIndex+1` for it to work
- for loop only executes once for provided set of arguments whereas it should execute at least twice
- Instead of assigning `Arrays.copyOfRange` to `subArray[row]`, we need to assign it to `subArray[<zero based index>]`

Below solution does work:

```
public double[][] get2DSubArray(double[][] largeArray, int rowStartIndex, int rowEndIndex, int columnStartIndex,
        int columnEndIndex) {
    double[][] subArray = new double[rowEndIndex - rowStartIndex + 1][columnEndIndex - columnStartIndex + 1];
    int index = 0;
    for (int row = rowStartIndex; row <= rowEndIndex; row++) {
        subArray[index++] = Arrays.copyOfRange(largeArray[row], columnStartIndex, columnEndIndex+1);
    }
    return subArray;
}
```

Comment: It would be more efficient if you subtracted rowStartIndex instead of creating a new variable.

Comment: Thanks. I added 1 to the columnEndIndex, used 'row <= rowEndIndex' instead of 'row < rowEndIndex', but didn't use the unnecessary 'index' variable (row-rowStartIndex) works fine, and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

If the row start was 500 and the end was 505, the variable in the for loop would start at 500 instead of 0. You want to replace "subArray[row] =" with "subArray[row-rowStartIndex] =". You are referencing where it would of been in the larger array compared to where the copy will be in the smaller array.

Edit:

//Fixed Version:

```
public static double[][] get2DSubArray(double[][] largeArray, int rowStartIndex, int rowEndIndex, int columnStartIndex,
            int columnEndIndex) {
        double[][] subArray = new double[rowEndIndex - rowStartIndex + 1][columnEndIndex - columnStartIndex + 1];
        for (int row = rowStartIndex; row <= rowEndIndex; row++) {
            subArray[row-rowStartIndex] = Arrays.copyOfRange(largeArray[row], columnStartIndex, columnEndIndex+1);
        }
        return subArray;
    }
```

Comment: I just changed that but am still getting the exception. It seems that Eclipse is not understanding that I want to make an actual matrix (2D Array), as it fails to recognize that there is a second column in my 2D Array. Here is my exact output (I am printing the matrix just to make sure it works) http://imgur.com/a/lmEDF